# iMac 27" Late 2015 - what ram to buy?

Tags: imac, upgrade, memory, hardware-recommendation

I'm waiting for my iMac 27" late 2015 4.0ghz i7 to arrive and I'm looking to buy a 32gb kit to upgrade. I've been browsing for an hour and I can't find any specific buyer guides or websites that sell Mac compatible memory (in the EU).

According to Apple's RAM specs, I managed to find this:  [PCPartPicker.com](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/memory/#s=301866&t=9&E=0&V=1350&Z=32768004)

This is what the Apple specs say:

- PC3-14900
- Unbuffered
- Nonparity
- 204-pin
- 1867MHz DDR3 SDRAM

Source: [Install memory in an iMac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201191)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You will need two "16GB Kits"** (four 8GB modules in total) to get the full 32GB.  I have personally done this in my 2012 iMac 27"

[image: iMac 32GB RAM Slots]

The memory that I recommend is [Crucial 16GB Kit (8GBx2) DDR3L - PN# CT2K8G3S186DM](http://radnex.us/Crucial_4GB_PC3-14900_SODIMM)

I recommend Crucial because they are very reliable and they have a [lifetime warranty](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/company-warranty).  There are brands that are cheaper, but (IMO) it's simply not worth the cost savings.  I have found that not only is the quality better (fewer failures with lifetime warranted memory versus non-lifetime warranted)  the customer service has always been much "stronger" in terms of getting faulty memory replaced.

Comment: Did you do that on a mid or late 2015 model?

Comment: Mine was a 2012.  But the upgrade is exactly the same.  The PN# I provided is specific to the 2015 as it matches the specs you outlined in your question.

Comment: Looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Accepting answer in 3 mins...

Answer (score 0):

I usually buy any branded memory with the same pins and MHz and it always work. But there are brand names that manufacture for Apple products, like [OWC](https://www.macsales.com). But Corsair and Crucial etc have memory sets as well, specifically designed for Mac:

[Adamanta](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016OZKL3A) | [ArchMemory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017V643PS) | [Crucial](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01979WD4U) | [Corsair](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EI5ZPLG)